# why class Set does not exists in scala?

Tags: scala, collections

There are many classes which inherit trait Set.
HashSet, TreeSet, etc.

And there's Object(could i call it companion object of trait Set? not in the case of class Set?) Set and trait Set.

It seems to me that just adding one more class "Set" to this list make it seems to be really easy to understand the structure.

is there any reason Class Set should not exists?

Comment: I don't see what you are missing. What would you use this class for? Where would you put it in the "structure"?

Comment: i think result type of Object Set.apply is ambiguous.
result of the object Set.apply has type Trait Set, and scala interpreter say it has type Trait Set, but what class then it really has?

i know that scala Trait is not at all same as java Interface, but i don't think trait itself can be a class though, am i wrong?

Comment: Traits are similar to Java interfaces... its just that they are more versatile.

Answer (score 4):

If you just need a set, use `Set.apply` and you will have a valid set that supports all important operations. You don't need to worry how is it implemented. It is prepared to work well for most use cases.

On the other hand, if performance of certain operations matters for you, create a concrete class for concrete implementation of set, and you will know exactly what you have.

In java you would write:

```
Set<String> strings = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
```

in scala you could as well have those types

```
val strings: Set[String] = HashSet("a", "b")
```

but you can also use a handy factory if you don't need to worry about the type and simply use

```
val strings = Set("a", "b")
```

and nothing is wrong with this, and I don't see how adding another class would help at all. It is normal thing to have an interface/trait and concrete implementations, nothing in the middle is needed nor helpful.

`Set.apply` is a factory for sets. You can check what is the actual class of resulting object using `getClass`. This factory creates special, optimized sets for sizes 0-4, for example

```
scala.collection.immutable.Set$EmptySet$
scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1
scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set2
```

for bigger sets it is a hash set, namely `scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet`.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala there is no overlap between classes and traits.  Classes are implementations that can be instantiated, while traits are independently mixable interfaces.  The use of Set.apply gives an object with interface Set and that is all you need to know to use it.  I fully understand wanting a concrete type, but that would be unnecessary.  The right thing to do here is save it to a val of type Set and use only the interface Set provides.

I know that may not be satisfying, but give it time and the Scala type system will make sense in terms of itself, even if that is different than what Java does.